# App Insights query triggers an error when run from code

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm trying to run a query on App Insights from a piece of Java code. I started from something extremely simple:

```
requests | where success == false
```

This query returns some results when I ran it directly in App Insights through Azure Portal. But then when I add this query to my code, I get this error:

```
Failure Exception: HttpResponseException: Status code 400, "{"error":{"message":"The request had some invalid properties","code":"BadArgumentError","correlationId":"22758365-9459-45ba-b4a3-1b134ce3a7a2","innererror":{"code":"SemanticError","message":"A semantic error occurred.","innererror":{"code":"SEM0100","message":"'where' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'requests'"}}}}"
```

In my code, I'm trying to execute it using LogsQueryClient. What can wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The LogsQueryClient sends the query to a workspace. So, I went ahead and tried to create a query for the workspace, not for the App Insights directly. When I did this, the generated query changed into:

```
AppRequests | where Success = false
```

and then it worked when executed from the code as well.